# How to get count of items in this data structure when label missing in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to get the count of significant items which is 60, which you can see when you do `str(res.r)` where you see the following where the fields do not have a name where I could refer. 
Normally, my data is made like `data.frame(V1, V2)`, you could do `res.r$V1` but here you cannot. 
I tried also unsuccessfully `res.r$1`.

```
#  ..$ : chr [1:60] "cyl" "disp" "hp" "wt" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "row" "col"
```

### Minimal example

Referring by `lista[[1]]` works with the simplest example

```
lista <- c( list(seq(1,5)), list(seq(1,7)) )

str(lista)

str(lista[[1]])
#List of 2
# $ : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# $ : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

### Code

Referring by `res.r[[1]]` does not work here as expected

```
library("corrplot")
library("psych")
library("gplots")

M.cor <- cor(mtcars)
p.mat <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)
alpha <- .0000005
plt.r <- corrplot(M.cor,
                method = "color",
                type = "upper",
                tl.col = 'black',
                diag = TRUE,
                p.mat = p.mat[["r"]],
                sig.level = alpha, 
                main = "r", 
                mar=c(0,0,1,0), # stackoverflow.com/a/14754408/… 
               )

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523080/54964
res.r <- which(p.mat[["r"]] < alpha, arr.ind = TRUE)
str(res.r)

# TODO here - how to get the count of significant item as num
```

Output

```
#Attaching package: ‘gplots’

#The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

#    lowess

# int [1:60, 1:2] 2 3 4 6 11 1 5 7 8 9 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:60] "cyl" "disp" "hp" "wt" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "row" "col"
```

Expected output: num of the significant items, here 60

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure is matrix, not a list of lists although it looks like that. 
Do

```
str(nrow(res.r))

str(ncol(res.r))
```

Output

```
Attaching package: ‘gplots’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    lowess

 int [1:60, 1:2] 2 3 4 6 11 1 5 7 8 9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:60] "cyl" "disp" "hp" "wt" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "row" "col"
 int 2
 int 3
 int 60
 int 2
```

Comment: do you need still help?